# Generating Random Instances from library Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random, actionscript, adobe

Hi hope someone can help me out in AS3. Below is code to generate 1 ball every 3 seconds.  There is a movieclip called "coin" which is in the library.And gets exported out on the stage every 3 seconds.

Question:  What I want to achieve is to have 8+  random movieclips created and linked to the "coin"  so when it gets exported it is not the same ball all the time so this is what I have for that:

var ballsArray:Array = [ball00,ball01,ball02,ball03,ball04,ball05,ball06,ball07,ball08];---- --- movieclips in the library

Question:  how do I get the coin to read this array  randomly so it doesnt go to "coin" movieclip"and just play the one ball i would like it go play random balls

thank you very much in advance

```
creates timer that runs every 3 seconds.  Number of times it runs 
is determined by the length of chosenNums array (which is the number
of numbers chosen)
```

var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000, chosenNums.length);

```
timer is listening for itself to trigger, calls chuckBall()
```

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, chuckBall);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, ballChuckingComplete);

```
chuckBall generates coins
```

function chuckBall(event:TimerEvent):void
{

```
  generates new Coin - Coin is the name of MovieClip in Library
  remember to export for Actionscript
var c1:Coin = new Coin();


   coin is placed at appropriate x and y coords
c1.x = kNum[chosenNums[chosenNumsIndex]].x;
c1.y = kNum[chosenNums[chosenNumsIndex]].y;



     addChild tells main timeline to display coin once it's generated.
this.addChild(c1);

trace(chosenNums[chosenNumsIndex])

     pull appropriate movieclip out of array and play to darken.
mcArray[chosenNums[chosenNumsIndex] - 1].play();

    fill in bottom numbers

      increments chosenNumsIndex so the next time chuckBall runs
      it pulls the next element of the chosenNums array.
      chosenNumsIndex ++;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of keeping instance of balls in your array you could keep their classes after that you could add a new created instance of the class to the coin instance.

for exemple:

```
// keep the classes of your balls. 
// In the library, the balls must be exported for actionScript with class names Ball00, Ball01, Ball02...
var ballsArray:Array = [Ball00, Ball01, Ball02, Ball03, Ball04, Ball05, Ball06, Ball07, Ball08];

// create your timer
var timer:Timer = new Timer( 3000, chosenNums.length );

// add your listeners
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, chuckBall); 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, ballChuckingComplete);

// generate balls
function chuckBall(event:TimerEvent):void 
{
    //generates new Coin - Coin is the name of MovieClip in Library remember to export for Actionscript
    var c1:Coin = new Coin();

    //coin is placed at appropriate x and y coords
    c1.x = kNum[chosenNums[chosenNumsIndex]].x;
    c1.y = kNum[chosenNums[chosenNumsIndex]].y;

    //addChild tells main timeline to display coin once it's generated.
    this.addChild(c1);

    // instanciate your ball
    var ball:MovieClip = new (mcArray[chosenNums[chosenNumsIndex] - 1] as Class)() as MovieClip;

    // add your ball to your coin if you want 
    c1.addChild( ball );

    // play the ball to darken.
    ball.play();

    //increments chosenNumsIndex so the next time chuckBall runs it pulls the next element of the chosenNums array.
    chosenNumsIndex ++;
}
```

I hope this will help you :)